# Intend to get a file content is array variable

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a file contains multiple array variable like this

some of content...

```
$variable = array(
    "a" => array("q" => "1",),
   "b" => array("w" => "2",),
);
```

some of content...

```
$variable = array(
  "c" => array("e" => "3",),
  "d" => array("w" => "4",),
);`
```

Izzit have any way that in file_get_contents and using preg_match_all to get content result like this

```
Array[0] = 
   $variable = array(
     "a" => array("q" => "1"),
     "b" => array("w" => "2"),
   );

Array[1] = 
   $variable = array(
     "c" => array("e" => "3",),
    "d" => array("w" => "4",),
);`
```

Or have other way that also can get the same result...

Thanks you

Comment: Is it a PHP file, please elaborate what's your goal here because I don't get what do you mean.

Comment: If it's PHP which has the array variables, just include it.

Comment: If all content of file is PHP, you can directly include it (since variable names are same, there may be data loss). Second alternative is using `eval` function after `preg_match_all`. It evaluates given string as code. [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: actually the php is a class file, inside have many functions and each of the function also have the variable, for my purpose is want to get the variable and the value only...